# How do i use XDomainRequest? Trying to access JSON cross domain Cors working for everything but IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xdomainrequest

I made some code that accesses a JSON file, extracts the objects and using jquery to append the html This is done using CORS. This works perfect in everything but IE 8 and 9.

I read that XDomainRequest is the way to go to make this work but i have no idea how.
Any Help is appreciated.

Please don't worry about the html1, click1 etc - everything works how it should in the complete file. I just need help with the XDomainRequest.

```
if(window.XDomainRequest){
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 

    xdr.open("get", "[link_to_JSON_on_different_server]");

    xdr.send();
} else {
    $.getJSON("[link_to_JSON_on_different_server]",function(data){
        if (click2){
            var href2 = click2 + encodeURIComponent(data.fuse[0].link);

        }else{
            var href2 = data.fuse[0].link;
        }

        if (click3){
            var href3 = click3 + encodeURIComponent(data.fuse[1].link);
        }else{
            var href3 = data.fuse[1].link;
        }
        $('#title').append('<a href="'+href2+'">'+data.fuse[0].title+'</a>');
        $('#favicon').append('<img style="padding-right:10px;max-width: 16px;" src="http://'+data.fuse[0].domain+'/favicon.ico"> '+data.fuse[0].domain+' ');
        $('#content').append(data.fuse[0].content);

        $('#read').append('<a href="'+href2+'">Read More ></a>');

        $('#title1').append('<a href="'+href3+'">'+data.fuse[1].title+'</a>');
        $('#favicon1').append('<img style="padding-right:10px;max-width: 16px;" src="http://'+data.fuse[1].domain+'/favicon.ico"> '+data.fuse[1].domain+' ');
        $('#content1').append(data.fuse[1].content);
        $('#read1').append('<a href="'+href3+'">Read More ></a>');
    });
}
```

**EDITS:**

I can't use JSONP.

I don't get an error. My problem is how do i extract the data using XDomainRequest, like i do with getJSON?

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
if(window.XDomainRequest){// 1. Create XDR object: 
var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 

xdr.onload = function() {
    var responseText = xdr.responseText;
    // TODO handle success response here.
obj = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);
$('#title').append('<a href="'+href2+'">'+obj.fuse[0].title+'</a>');
alert('success');
};

xdr.onerror = function() {
    // The request has failed.  No specific information will be provided by XDR unfortunately. 
    alert('fail');
};

xdr.open("get", "[link_to_JSON_on_different_server]");
xdr.send();
} else {
            $.getJSON("[link_to_JSON_on_different_server]",function(data){
if (click2){
 var href2 = click2 + encodeURIComponent(data.fuse[0].link);

}else{
var href2 = data.fuse[0].link;
}

if (click3){
 var href3 = click3 + encodeURIComponent(data.fuse[1].link);
}else{
var href3 = data.fuse[1].link;
}
             $('#title').append('<a href="'+href2+'">'+data.fuse[0].title+'</a>');
             $('#favicon').append('<img style="padding-right:10px;max-width: 16px;" src="http://'+data.fuse[0].domain+'/favicon.ico"> '+data.fuse[0].domain+' ');
             $('#content').append(data.fuse[0].content);
             $('#read').append('<a href="'+href2+'">Read More ></a>');

             $('#title1').append('<a href="'+href3+'">'+data.fuse[1].title+'</a>');
             $('#favicon1').append('<img style="padding-right:10px;max-width: 16px;" src="http://'+data.fuse[1].domain+'/favicon.ico"> '+data.fuse[1].domain+' ');
             $('#content1').append(data.fuse[1].content);
             $('#read1').append('<a href="'+href3+'">Read More ></a>');
         });
         }
```

Comment: You're using jQuery, it already polyfills everything you'd need for an ajax request cross browser.

Comment: No it doesn't... This is one case in particular where it does not polyfil. there are plugins available for it though.

Comment: Are you going from http to https? What is the error you get?

Comment: XDomainRequest is quite limited, and, as a result, fairly simple to use.  The API is a subset of that provided by XMLHttpRequest.  I see no issue with your code, so what specific issue are you having?

Comment: @KevinB - Yes it does, but it does not include XDomainRequest, and there's a very good reason for that, it sucks.

Comment: Right, but the whole point of this question is that XDomainRequest is your only option for performing CORS requests in old IE, and it isn't working in this particular case. Most likely due to one of the restrictions listed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: Nope, the only viable option is to make the request from the serverside, or just drop support for older browsers and move on to JSONP instead.

Comment: Please see added info

Comment: I suspected you were simply looking for a way to extract the data from the response.  See my answer.  The XDomainRequest API is outlined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx for future reference.

Comment: The same way you would with XMLHttpRequest, with an onload handler and accessing the responseText.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may be unsure how to get a handle on the server response when using XDomainRequest, since I see no errors in your code.  As I mentioned in my comment, the API for XDomainRequest is a subset of that provided by XMLHttpRequest.  So, to grab the response, your code should look something like this:

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 

xdr.onload = function() {
    var responseText = xdr.responseText;
    // TODO handle success response here.
};

xdr.onerror = function() {
    // The request has failed.  No specific information will be provided by XDR unfortunately.  
};

xdr.open("get", "[link_to_JSON_on_different_server]");
xdr.send();
```

Comment: This is closer to helping me understand, but the big question is how do i extract the objects? for getJSON it was data.fuse[0].title, but what would it be for xdr?

Comment: You will need to parse the JSON yourself.  You can achieve this via `JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);`.

Comment: So i created this code:

obj = JSON.parse(xdr.responseTex);
$('#title').append('<a href="'+href2+'">'+obj.fuse[0].title+'</a>');
};

But nothing happens in ie. Even a simple alert('test'); won't trigger in the xdr.onload

Comment: It's `xdr.responseText`, NOT `xdr.responseTex`.  Also, if onload is not triggered, then the request is failing due to an issue with the server response.

Comment: fixed the spelling mistake - my bad, but still doesn't work. What do you think could be the issue with the server response? I wish there could be a little more information xdr would give as to why it's failing

Comment: Is your onerror triggered?  If so, the issue is definitely with the server response.  You'll have to examine the server response with the aid of a proxy.  You're right, unfortunately, XDomainRequest is not very useful when it comes to determining why a request has failed, but this is not much different from XMLHttpRequest in the context of cross-domain response errors.

Comment: No. Niether triggers. Will try using fiddler to trace the headers and see what i can see. Don't really know what i'm looking for though.

Comment: What does your modified code look like now?  Post an UPDATE to your original question.

Comment: You'll probably want to make sure your server is actually handling the request properly as well.  This might be easier that examining the traffic via a proxy.

Comment: how do i check something like that?

Comment: Set breakpoints or logging statements in the appropriate locations

Answer (score 0):

XDomainRequest is the way to make it work. If you are using jQuery 1.5 or better, I suggest you use the following script.

https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

This script transparently adds support for CORS to $.ajax in IE 8 and 9. Just drop it in somewhere after your jQuery script and watch it work.

jQuery doesn't support XDomainRequest out of the box(http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) but as of jQuery 1.5 you can define a custom transport to handle CORS in IE 8 & 9.

Comment: dropping that code in just doesn't do anything. it continues to work in firefox and to not work in IE 8 and 9

Comment: did you remove the if statement checking if XDomainRequest is present? If it's still in your code please remove it. Once you include the script you only need to call $.ajax and it will use the XDomainRequest in IE 8 & 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery plugin [jquery-transport-xdr](https://github.com/gfdev/javascript-jquery-transport-xdr) to enable **CORS** requests in IE8/9.